# Accessing network drive from C# code in asp.net mvc application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, file

I m using the file upload and trying to save the file into a folder created.I want to keep this folder in the network drive but when I try to access that drive it says access denied. I m able to access a path on the c drive and store it but these docs needs to be in the common folder and i m unable to get it to work. any idea. ?

```
 <add key="FolderPath" value="\\example.com\Root\CTFiles\IMSDocs" />
```

Comment: Give the permissions to that directory. If your code is uploading files to this, you need to give the IIS process permission (IUser)

Comment: The user account that is running the app pool that's hosting your website is the account that requires both access to the folder on the hard drive AND ALSO access to the network share.  Tada.

Comment: create a webservice or wcf project, and add two methods upload and download, and let  this application to be published on the machine that contains the shared folder, and then use this wcf or webservice as a reference in your project.